# не могу изменить значение глобальной переменной javascript

Tags: javascript

Дается массив `args`, с помощь счетчиков ведется подсчет единиц.

Но в конце выводится значение счетчиков равняется нулю. Хотя единицы есть!

В чем может быть проблема? Такоe ощущение что счетчики каждый раз обнуляются. Как этого избежать? Бьюсь уже 1,5 часа.

```js
var args = [
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1],
];
var counter_first = 0;
var counter_second = 0;
for (b of args) {
  for (a of b) {

    if (a[0] == 1 && (counter_first % 2 == 0)) {
      a[0] = -1;

    }
    if (a[0] == 1) {
      counter_first = counter_first + 1;
    }

    if (a[1] == 1 && (counter_second % 2 == 0)) {
      a[1] = -1;


    }
    if (a[1] == 1) {
      counter_second = counter_second + 1;
    }

  }
  console.log(counter_first + " counter_first");
  console.log(counter_second + " counter_second")

}
```

Comment: Но ведь `a[0]`, `a` - не массив

Comment: a - массив [1, 1]

Comment: Нет, у Вас `a` это отдельно сначала 1, а потом 1. Вы же сами проходитесь по всех подмассивах, а потом по каждом элементе этого подмассива.

Comment: В общем, у Вас там никогда не выполняется условие, что один из элементов равен 1, потому что Вы присваиваете -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы меняете элементы массива на `-1`, а потом проверяете, не равны ли они единице. Не равны.

```js
var args = [
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1],
];
var counter_first = 0;
var counter_second = 0;
for (a of args) {
//  for (a of b) {

    if (a[0] == 1 && (counter_first % 2 == 0)) {
//      a[0] = -1;
    }
    if (a[0] == 1) {
      counter_first = counter_first + 1;
    }
    if (a[1] == 1 && (counter_second % 2 == 0)) {
 //     a[1] = -1;
    }
    if (a[1] == 1) {
      counter_second = counter_second + 1;
    }
//  }
  console.log(counter_first + " counter_first");
  console.log(counter_second + " counter_second")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно, от души